# How to make App Engine app in Google Cloud public?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've created an app in Google App Engine, added one PHP file and deployed it running commands:

```
gcloud app deploy
gcloud app browse
```

I then received the URL to the website. The problem is that when I try to enter this URL in privacy mode of the browser, it asks me to login with my Gmail account.

How to set up the URL to public?

**Update:** I have Google Cloud Platform Free Tier

Comment: Show us your app.yaml, the request you make and the handler code handling that request.

Comment: You may also want to go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in app.yaml, I just deleted strings "login: admin".